# Why would a server deliver packets faster and more frequently to an iPhone than a PC?

Tags: javascript, ios, server, wireshark, keil

Brief overview:
I am running Keil's HTTP Web Server on a board.  The HTML page runs a JavaScript loop which fetches the file dynamic.cgx every 50 milliseconds.

When only a singular device is on the network, the file is delivered reliably every 50ms, the fetch taking 1-2ms on average.  The moment another device connects, packet delivery slows down, waiting more than 500ms to respond to the fetch request.

On an iPhone, this issue does not occur.  A bit of slowdown is seen, but not nearly to the level of the PC.  This is not due to Safari, as the iPhone Google browser worked equally well.

[WireShark with 1 PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbNRs.png)

[WireShark with PC + Device (PC POV)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW5Z9.png)

I can't packet sniff with a mobile device right now, so those aren't included

Comment: Have you tried simulating multiple sessions on the same PC at the same time? I would disable caching on the browser to make sure a fresh file is requested each time. It sounds like there might be a synchronous process occuring. I would look long polling or websockets for connections that need to continuously poll data.

Comment: Yes, cache is disabled during simulation, but usually 2 pcs are used for testing.
But what would cause the iPhones to work fine even when the PCs do not?  When 2 iphones and 2 pcs were on, the pcs barely got anything while the iphones ran at nearly full speed.

Comment: `iPhone Google browser`  You do know that is still Safari right.   Apple's, strict policy's mean, Chrome on IOS is just Safari in different clothes.

Comment: @Keith in that case do you know why Safari would be faster?  Does it issue higher priority fetch requests than other browsers or process JavaScript more efficiently, thereby reducing the fetch time?

Comment: [Was this you asking the same question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72736508/why-would-a-server-be-slower-on-ethernet-than-through-a-phone) under a different name?

Comment: That's probs my co-worker lol, didn't think he used SO

Comment: It could be a number of things, but generally speaking embdeded HTTP servers are not really meant for concurrent connections, it's likely it's just running single thread to process HTTP requests, the 500ms might be the default `keep-alive` timeout, so while the first connection holds onto this connection it can't process another request.  You could maybe see if Keils server has the option to turn of keep-alives and see if that helps.  Of course disabling the keep-alives would make single connections slower, but not by a massive amount..

Comment: I see your also using wireshark, so you might find you can disable HTTP `keep-alive`'s there..  I'm sure there will be a setting somewhere, I don't use either Keil or Wireshark so maybe somebody else can recomend were you change these settings.